# Passing req.user to template not working with ejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using EJS and Express to take and check if the current user exists and if not show one thing instead of the other. My issue is that I am setting `req.user` to `res.locals.currentUser` but it is not passing through to the template so I can output it as well as check if it exists.

**in my app.js**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
   next();
});
```

**my ejs file**

```
<% if(!currentUser){ %>
    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/register">Sign Up</a></li>
<% } else { %>
    <li><a href="#">Signed In As <%= currentUser.email %></a></li>
    <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
<% } %>
```

This evaluates always to false therefore showing the first section of the if statement.

What is wrong here to make it so I can't test or see the user data in my ejs view? When I console.log the `currentUser` is returns undefined.

Some information that might be important, I am using a redis session store instead of mongo store. I also am using body-parser not cookieparser.

Comment: can you add `console.log(res.locals.currentUser);` to app.js after the function to see what that returns?

Comment: @awesomeguy It is still just `undefined` the same as if I console.log from inside my view. `req.user` shows the user properly though

Comment: That does not do much feeling. Are you sure that req.user exists? Does a console.log in this middleware display the user?  <%=JSON.stringify(locals.currentUser)%> does not exist?

Comment: @AMS It does exist because when I console.log it during the request it exists but console.log of currentUser show undefined.

Comment: @AMS I put that EJS string in my view and it outputs nothing.

Comment: @joshk132 So if you are using passport or just session, you should be simple by the user in locals. I a similar middleware to per in locals. [middleware example](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/middle-jpg)

Comment: @AMS Thanks that worked much better than the solution I was working on which was trying to make a render view function that worked.

Comment: @joshk132 How good are we there to try to help us.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while using Passport in node.js with ejs templating.

The solution is to place it below the passport lines of code( that is serialize and deserialize).
These functions are responsible for saving the user to "req.user", and thus if the app.use is placed above it, the code won't work as req.user is null until this.

Adios